# How to pull from remote repo to remote branch

Tags: git, visual-studio

We use git through visualstudio.com.
Each developer has their own branch off master. The usual morning process is:

1. go to XXXXX.visualstudio.com
2. Create pull request from master to my branch.
3. in visual studio on my machine, pull the branch to my machine and start working.

I know i can do step 3 via command line.
Is step 2 possible via command line on my pc, i.e pull from remote master to remote branch before pulling the remote branch to my machine?

Comment: Why are you creating a pull request from _master_ to _your_ feature branch?

Comment: Its our process. Each developer does this daily, works on thier assigned tasks, merges the branch back into the master at the end of the day, and at the start of the next day we all get the updated master so were working from the same base. It may not be the ideal workflow, but it works. To the specific question asked, is it possible to do step 3 via command line on my machine?

Comment: I don't have much familiarity with visualstudio.com, however a Pull Request is not a concept of Git. Most likely, what you are ending up with is a call to git pull --some-options. If you were able to pinpoint which option (if any), you should be able to do that locally. One issue might be when pushing that (auths). This assuming you are not asking about visualstudio.com APIs on how to open the request via CLI from local to remote.

Answer (score 0):

Your workflow is very non standard, and also would be confusing to many seasoned Git users.  Here is a better workflow:

```
# from my_branch
git fetch origin
git merge origin/master
```

The first `git fetch` step will update your *local* tracking branch `origin/master` with the latest changes from the true *remote* `master` branch.  Then, also locally, you may merge the latest `master` into your feature branch, and go from there.

Comment: Thanks, but thr question is not about weather thr workflow is standard or not. There are reasons this one is in place. As per the strict rules here, I asked a very specific question.

Comment: Stack Overflow tries to always give you the _best_ answer, which is what I have done here.  If you can change your workflow to something more normal, you should.